# Plugin won't activate

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to redirect a user once they click "activate" on my plugin, the redirect is working great using the register_activation_hook however the plugin is failing to activate.

Any thoughts on what i need to do to make it run the hook after activation and not before?

```
function install_redirect() {
wp_redirect('http://www.mydomain.com');exit;
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_redirect');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450510/redirect-after-plugin-activation

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_redirect');

function my_plugin_activate() {
    add_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function my_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('my_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
        wp_redirect(MY_PLUGIN_SETTINGS_URL);
    }
}
```